# Problems passing source command to bash from c++ application

Tags: c++, bash, qt, command-line, environment-variables

I am developing an application for work that allows the users to quickly set environment variables on a terminal basis. By setting the path in each terminal we ensure files with the same name in different directories aren't causing application testing to be problematic. I am Using Qt to build the program which is c++ based and all the datatypes are foundationally the same.

I am using the following code to invoke commands in the terminal from which the application launches from using *system()*. **I can run commands into the bash just fine with code; however, I run into a problem when I attempt to use a command with arguments.** *This is probably why source doesn't seem to work right as the source command is followed by the filename.* It would appear that I drop the argument appended after the bash command.

My Code:

```
void assignTerminalToPath(QString path)
{
    QString data = "";
    QString currentUsersHomeDirectory = QDir::homePath();
    QString tmpScriptLocation = currentUsersHomeDirectory;
    QByteArray ba;
    tmpScriptLocation += "/.tmpSourceFile";
    QFile tmpSourceFile(tmpScriptLocation);
    if(tmpSourceFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate))
    {
        QTextStream output(&tmpSourceFile);
        data.append("export PATH=.:");
        data.append(path);
        data.append(":$PATH");
        output << QString("#!/bin/bash\n");
        output << data;
        tmpSourceFile.close();
    }
    data.clear();
    data.append("/bin/bash -c source ");
    data.append(tmpScriptLocation);
    ba = data.toLatin1();
    const char *cStr = ba.data();
    system(cStr);
}
```

Perhaps I'm not referencing bash correctly and I need something outside of -c?

Reference [Execute shell/bash command using C/C++](http://www.serverhostingsecrets.com/tutorials/execute-shell-command-using-cc/)

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Even if `source` was an external command, what you'd be running would have absolutely zero effect. The changes in environment that would result would be for the subshell only, never visible from your process or anything else on your system. What are you trying to do?

Comment: As you use Qt, you should use QProcess, which has API for changing environment variables, among other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source` is not a program that you can call, it is embedded bash command. It is designed to be processed by bash without invoking another copy of bash, such that environment variables can be changed in current bash copy.

However, you cannot call source as part of `system()`. And even if you did succeed at that, its effects to change environment variables would be completely lost for caller app once `system()` has returned.

Comment: alright alright! lol! looks like your gonna get a two for one! I suppose the right answer in this case is to supply the user with the export code to run in their terminal or launch a new terminal from the application. Thanks for your insight! You were a great help!

Answer (score -1):

Try a command to envelop with parameters in double quotes ("command - arg1 - to arg2") to transfer in the function system().

used:

char *com = "\"command -arg1 -arg2\"";

system(com);